# Primeng virtualscroll offset like peagination

Tags: angular, primeng

im using primeng table..

I have this onLazyLoad function

```
this.apiService.getUsers(this.searchQuery,event.sortField,event.sortOrder===-1? "desc" : "asc",****** PAGE ******).subscribe(
  res=>{
    if(res){
      this.users=res.data.concat(this.users );
    }
  }
```

then

```
p-table [value]="users" (onLazyLoad)="onLazyLoad($event)" [rows]="20" [resetPageOnSort]="true" [resizableColumns]="true" [scrollHeight]="'calc(100vh - 210px)'" [virtualScroll]="true" [virtualRowHeight]="40" [lazy]="true">
```

Is it possible to get current scrolled page to use on BE for pagination? Or i have to change backend to work with event.first and event.rows

Answer (score 0):

```
@ViewChild("table") table: Table;

this.table.virtualPage
```

This worked for me, but im still looking for similliar solution if there is any.